# Nginx wont redirect to www

Tags: nginx, url, redirect

Hello I have hard times to configure nginx properly. I would like redirect from https://example.com to https://www.example.com I found a lot of tutorials how to do it but not a single one worked with mine configuration files.
I used letsencrpyt to configure the SSL for me.
Here is the nginx conf file:

```
server {
  server_name IP_ADDRESS example.com www.example.com;

  location /static/ {
      root /home/user/pyapps/ks_g;
  }

  location /media/ {
      root /home/user/pyapps/ks_g;    
  }

  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
   if ($host = www.example.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot 

   listen 80;
   server_name IP_ADDRESS example.com www.example.com;
   return 404; # managed by Certbot
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add redirect on condition to the server block with SSL or both:

```
   if ($host != www.example.com) {
      return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
   } # managed by Stack Overflow (sorry cannot hold myself)
```

This works as the following: if the `Host` HTTP header not equals `www.example.com` make permanent redirect to `https://www.example.com$request_uri`.